get req in NestJs without injecting @Req()
in NestJs we can access the request like this
@Get("/")
getUsers(@req() req){ ... }

how to access req without using @Req?
use case:
I'm trying to generate a method dynamically using Reflect, using param decorators is invalid here
this.target.prototype.getUsers = function(@Req() req request){ ... }

using @Req() here is invalid, and without it, req is undefined

you can have a request-scoped provider instead of a singleton and inject the REQUEST provider as the docs shows here: https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/injection-scopes#request-provider. I'm not saying that this is good but it's the only way if you don't want to use the @Req() decorator.
Here's a good resource on how those decorators are used by nestjs: https://trilon.io/blog/nestjs-metadata-deep-dive

as I understand you want to inject REQUEST in the service, but I don't have any control of the service, I just can generate a route method by a class decorator. however I need to access req in the route method (i.e. in the controller) @Micael Levi

controllers are injectable as well so you can inject REQUEST on controllers
